# Is it possible to instantiate a Ruby class without calling initialize?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

Some times when I write unit tests I need to instantiate a class without the `initialize` method being invoked. For instance when the constructor instantiates other classes that I will replace with stubs anyway. For instance:

```
class SomeClassThatIWillTest
  def initialize
    @client = GoogleAnalyticsClient.new
    @cache = SuperAdvancedCacheSystem.new
  end

  # ...
end
```

In a test I will probably replace both `@client` and `@cache` with stubs, so I'd rather the constructor was never invoked. Is there any black magic that can help me out with that?

Comment: What about subclassing `SomeClassThatIWillTest` and overwriting `initialize` in the subclass? No black magic involved ;)

Comment: @tessi: That's a really nice idea! And it worked brilliantly.

Comment: @Codemonkey No I take it back partially - if it is going to manage them internally from instantiation to destruction (without external modification) they may not need to be injected. Please read over http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130711/should-i-pass-an-object-into-a-constructor-or-instantiate-in-class

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Then we agree

Comment: @Codemonkey glad I could help. I'll write this as an answer (as it really was an answer actually)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure you can. `Class#new` is nothing more than a convenience method that saves you from having to allocate and initialize an object manually. Its implementation looks roughly like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, **kwargs, &blk)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, **kwargs, &blk)
    obj
  end
end
```

You can just call `Class#allocate` manually instead, and not call `initialize`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `def self.new`? Thanks for the information.

Comment: No, `new` is an instance method of class `Class`. There is *also* a `Class::new` singleton method, but that creates new classes, i.e. instances of `Class`. `Class#new` creates instances of the instances of `Class`, i.e. instances of classes.

Answer (score 4):

You should not change behavior of tested class in order to unit test it. If your class will have more actions in constructor you will have to mimic it every time. Your test will get tedious to maintain. Replace objects (or even classes) with doubles.

Maybe you could provide already created objects as an arguments to the constructor? It would allow you to use doubles without stubbing `new` method on classes.

If you are using rspec, you can:

```
GoogleAnalyticsClient.stub(new: double)
SuperAdvancedCacheSystem.stub(new: double)
```

Define your doubles to match expected interface, and voila! No dirty tricks needed.

Answer (score 1):

What about subclassing `SomeClassThatIWillTest` and overwriting `initialize` in the subclass? No black magic involved ;)

This way you could even call the `super` initializer (to test its code, if its more than you showed us), and then alter `@client` and `@cache` afterwards.

Example of a MiniTest spec using this method:

```
describe MyTestClass do

  subject {
    Class.new(MyTestClass) {
      def initialize; end
    }
  }

  it "must do something" do
    subject.new.do_something.must_equal something
    # ...
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrote my own answer with a code sample after I read your comment, so I just deleted my answer and added the code sample to your answer. Hope that's cool.

Comment: you are no longer testing the class that was suppossed to be tested but a subclass thereof which might (unintended) change the behavior and you don't want to change the behavior of what you are testing (which this question is actually proposing I know)

Comment: @RuneFS: you pretty much have to change the default behaviour in one way or another when testing classes that send requests to external services.

Comment: @Codemonkey if you inject your dependencies you don't need to change the bahavior of the class under test

Comment: @RuneFS: It feels wrong to change so much of the production code just for the unit tests... I'll never need dependency injection except in the case of the unit tests.

Comment: @Codemonkey I guess that's where our oppinions differ. To me it feels wrong not to test the actual code in production but to test a derivative thereof instead