# Why Ruby inheritance behave differently from other OOP language? is there any intent?

Tags: java, ruby, oop, inheritance

I have some dumb questions. Other OOP languages such as Java, when you make Child objects which inheritance Parent, Parent's constructor will be called automatically.

```java
public class Parent {
    
    public Parent() {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }

}

public class Child extends Parent {
    
    public Child() {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }

}


public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
    }

}
```

**result**

```
Parent
Child
```

But when you try same thing in Ruby, it behaves differently.

```rb
class Parent

    def initialize
        puts "Parent"
    end

end
```

```
require './parent'

class Child < Parent

    def initialize
        puts "Child"
    end

end
```

and If you create main like this,

```rb
require './parent'
require './child'

c = Child.new # This will only print 'Child'
```

**result from ruby**

```
❯ ruby main.rb
Child
```

Why is this?
If this is intentional, why ruby's inheritance designed this way? I suppose there will be a purpose for this. Anyone can explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not behavior unique to Ruby. Some languages require that you explicitly call the superclasses function. In this case, for the same behavior, `Child#initialize` would call `super` then would do `puts 'Child'`. As far as why it might work this way, there may be cases when you don't want the superclasses initialization actions to occur on the child class.

Comment: I know if I put `super` it will invoke parent constructor. That's not my question. In java `super()` is automatically called in child's constructor. why ruby does not do this? - when you don't want the superclasses initialization actions -> when is this usefull?

Comment: I also indicated in my comment when it is useful. By requiring the use of `super` that puts the control in the programmer's hands whether the superclass' initializer actions are performed in the child class.

Comment: I saw your comments. but It didn't convince me. if you don't want to invoke the superclass's method. then what is the point of inheritance?  I appreciate your comments tho.

Comment: Because with inheritance, you get all the superclasses methods. You don't have to rewrite them. If you just want the superclasses method, you don't write your own for the child class. If you write one for the child class and you want it to also perform the actions of the superclass, you call `super`.

Comment: I suppose, ruby's `initialize` is not a constructor. Rather it's just normal method happen to be called when it's instantiated. I see your point. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are correct about `initialize`. It's a class initializer, not a constructor. Ruby actually borrowed a lot of concepts from old Smalltalk. Smalltalk's behavior is the same in this regard.

Comment: @JinLim: "Rather it's just normal method happen to be called when it's instantiated." – It is *even simpler* than that. "It's just a normal method". Period. *Even* the fact that is seems to be "magically" called can be easily explained, because the method `Class#new` simply looks like this: `def new(*args) new_obj = allocate; new_obj.initialize(*args); return new_obj; end`. So, it doesn't even get called by some magic mechanism, it simply gets called because … well, it gets called. And `Class#new` is not magic either, it is a normal method you can override, etc. Even `Class#allocate` is a …

Comment: … normal method which you can override, call yourself, etc. The only thing "magic" about it, is that it is impossible to write its default implementation in Ruby, because you need to allocate an empty Ruby object, and set its class pointer, both of which is not possible in Ruby. But that is only the *inside implementation* of `Class#allocate`. From the outside, it, too, is a normal method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag There's actually something magic about `#initialize` (and a few other methods): its visibility defaults to `private`. Calling `public` or `protected` without an argument before its definition won't affect its visibility. This behavior doesn't have anything to do with OPs question though.

Answer (score 2):

Like people have mentioned in the comments above, while `#initialize` is called a "Ruby constructor", in Java parlance more like a "object init method", see this question about [`#allocate` vs `#initialize` in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982538/is-it-possible-to-instantiate-a-ruby-class-without-calling-initialize).

If you're coming from Java, know that Ruby classes aren't "static", in the Java sense, and Ruby objects aren't simply just instances of that static class. In order to implement Ruby's dynamicism, Ruby's classes are instances themselves of the class, `Class`, and they have a "eigenclass" or `singleton_class`, so the class inheritance graph is [more complicated](https://timnew.me/blog/2012/08/23/ruby-class-inheritance/).

If you stick with strictly "normal" code, you won't run into too many weirdnesses, but once you start metaprogramming heavily in Ruby, understanding this will be very important.